# Merging word counts with Bash and Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, grep

I made a Bash script that extracts words from a text file with **grep** and **sed** and then sorts them with **sort** and counts the repetitions with **wc**, then sort again by frequency. The example output looks like this:

```
12 the
 7 code
 7 with
 7 add
 5 quite
 3 do
 3 well
 1 quick
 1 can
 1 pick
 1 easy
```

Now I'd like to merge  all words with the same frequency into one line, like this:

```
12 the
 7 code with add
 5 quite
 3 do well
 1 quick can pick easy
```

Is there any way to do that with Bash and standard Unix toolset? Or I would have to write a script / program in some more sophisticated scripting language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ echo "12 the
 7 code
 7 with
 7 add
 5 quite
 3 do
 3 well
 1 quick
 1 can
 1 pick
 1 easy" | awk '{cnt[$1]=cnt[$1] ? cnt[$1] OFS $2 : $2} END {for (e in cnt) print e, cnt[e]} ' | sort -nr
12 the
7 code with add
5 quite
3 do well
1 quick can pick easy
```

You can do something similar with Bash 4 associative arrays. `awk` is easier and POSIX though. Use that.

---

Explanation:

1. `awk` splits the line apart by the separator in FS, in this case the default of horizontal whitespace;
2. `$1` is the first field of the count - use that to collect items with the same count in an associative array keyed by the count with `cnt[$1]`;
3. `cnt[$1]=cnt[$1] ? cnt[$1] OFS $2 : $2` is a ternary assignment - if `cnt[$1]` has no value, just assign the second field `$2` to it (The RH of `:`). If it does have a previous value, concatenate `$2` separated by the value of `OFS` (the LH of `:`);
4. At the end, print out the value of the associative array.

Since awk associative arrays are unordered, you need to sort again by the numeric value of the first column. `gawk` can sort internally, but it is just as easy to call `sort`. The input to awk does not need to be sorted, so you can eliminate that part of the pipeline.

---

If you want the digits to be right justified (as your have in your example):

```
$ awk '{cnt[$1]=cnt[$1] ? cnt[$1] OFS $2 : $2} 
     END {for (e in cnt) printf "%3s %s\n", e, cnt[e]} '
```

---

If you want `gawk` to [sort numerically by descending values](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning), you can add `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"` prior to traversing the array:

```
$ gawk '{cnt[$1]=cnt[$1] ? cnt[$1] OFS $2 : $2} 
            END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"
               for (e in cnt) printf "%3s %s\n", e, cnt[e]} '
```

Comment: Explanation added. If you are going to do any non trivial stuff in the shell, learn `awk` It is a required part of a POSIX shell.

Answer (score 2):

With single GNU ***awk*** expression (without `sort` pipeline):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc" }
     { a[$1]=(a[$1])? a[$1]" "$2:$2 }END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

The output:

```
12 the
7 code with add
5 quite
3 do well
1 quick can pick easy
```

---

**Bonus** alternative solution using GNU `datamash` tool:

```
datamash -W -g1 collapse 2 <file
```

The output (comma-separated collapsed fields):

```
12  the
7   code,with,add
5   quite
3   do,well
1   quick,can,pick,easy
```

Answer (score 2):

awk:

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] FS $2}!b[$1]++{d[++c]=$1}END{while(i++<c)print d[i],a[d[i]]}' file
```

sed:

```
sed -r ':a;N;s/(\b([0-9]+).*)\n\s*\2/\1/;ta;P;D'
```

Answer (score 1):

You start with sorted data, so you only need a new line when the first field changes.

```
echo "12 the
 7 code
 7 with
 7 add
 5 quite
 3 do
 3 well
 1 quick
 1 can
 1 pick
 1 easy" |
awk '
   {
      if ($1==last) { 
         printf(" %s",$2) 
      } else { 
         last=$1;
         printf("%s%s",(NR>1?"\n":""),$0)
      }
    }; END {print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

next time you find yourself trying to manipulate text with a combination of grep and sed and shell and..., stop and just use awk instead - the end result will be clearer, simpler, more efficient, more portable, etc...

```
$ cat file
It was the best of times, it was the worst of times,
it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness.
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[^[:alpha:]]+" }
{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        word2cnt[tolower($i)]++
    }
}
END {
    for (word in word2cnt) {
        cnt = word2cnt[word]
        cnt2words[cnt] = (cnt in cnt2words ? cnt2words[cnt] " " : "") word
        printf "%3d %s\n", cnt, word
    }
    for (cnt in cnt2words) {
        words = cnt2words[cnt]
        # printf "%3d %s\n", cnt, words
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -rn
  4 was
  4 the
  4 of
  4 it
  2 times
  2 age
  1 worst
  1 wisdom
  1 foolishness
  1 best
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[^[:alpha:]]+" }
{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        word2cnt[tolower($i)]++
    }
}
END {
    for (word in word2cnt) {
        cnt = word2cnt[word]
        cnt2words[cnt] = (cnt in cnt2words ? cnt2words[cnt] " " : "") word
        # printf "%3d %s\n", cnt, word
    }
    for (cnt in cnt2words) {
        words = cnt2words[cnt]
        printf "%3d %s\n", cnt, words
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -rn
  4 it was of the
  2 age times
  1 best worst wisdom foolishness
```

Just uncomment whichever `printf` line you like in the above script to get whichever type of output you want. The above will work in any awk on any UNIX system.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider that. I guess I have to learn awk some more :J

Comment: BTW your example might omit compounds like "message-driven", "by-laws" etc., or genitives like "Joe's", or other combinations with the apostrophe (like "ma'am"). But I guess I just need to update the regexp to the one I used with sed...

Comment: @BarbaraKwarc - next time, you can avoid this confusion by including your code in your question.

Comment: My code was irrelevant. It was about its output, and its post-processing. I could generate the same output multiple different ways, so what would be the point in obfuscating my question with it? :q

Comment: @BarbaraKwarc - in that case, the entire first sentence of your question amounts to misdirection, as it makes this look like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). If it doesn't matter how you got your input, don't tell us how you got your input.

Answer (score 0):

Using [miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/)'s `nest` verb:

```
mlr -p  nest --implode --values --across-records -f 2 --nested-fs ' ' file
```

Output:

```
12 the
7 code with add
5 quite
3 do well
1 quick can pick easy
```