# Extracting second column besides first unique column

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I've text file with email id and some organization id like this -

```
user1.org1@gmail.com 7001
user1.org1@gmail.com 5400
user1.org1@gmail.com A296
user1.org1@gmail.com 1008
user2@gmail.com 7018
user2@gmail.com 5420
user2@gmail.com A996
user3.org2@gmail.com 1018
user3.org2@gmail.com 7021
```

All email id are sorted alphabetically. These data are stored in `user_data.txt` file.
I want to print the output like this in terminal or text file like this way -

```
user1.org1@gmail.com 7001, 5400, A296, 1008
user2@gmail.com 7018, 5420, A996
user3.org2@gmail.com 1018, 7021
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging word counts with Bash and Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027733/merging-word-counts-with-bash-and-unix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the always-useful [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ datamash -W -g1 collapse 2 < user_data.txt
user1.org1@gmail.com    7001,5400,A296,1008
user2@gmail.com 7018,5420,A996
user3.org2@gmail.com    1018,7021
```

(Use one or more whitespace characters instead of single tabs as the input column delimiter, group by the first column and collapse the second column values of each group into a CSV list).

---

Alternatives if you don't have `datamash` and can't install it:

`perl`:

```
perl -lane 'push @{$groups{$F[0]}}, $F[1];
            END {
              for $g (sort keys %groups) {
                print "$g ", join(",", @{$groups{$g}})
            }}' user_data.txt
```

`awk`:

```
awk '{ if ($1 in groups)
         groups[$1] = groups[$1] "," $2
       else
         groups[$1] = $2
     }
     END {
       PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" # Sort output if using GNU awk
       for (g in groups) print g, groups[g]
     }' user_data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Also in shell script:

```
unset b
while read a c; do
    if [ "$b" = "$a" ]; then
        printf ', %s'  "$c"
    else
        [ "$b" ] && echo
        printf '%s %s'  "$a" "$c"
        b="$a"
    fi
done < user_data.txt
echo
```